# PostgreSQL 10 logical replication only synchronizing one time and then stopping

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have one database containing user information that I'm replicating to a separate application db on the same cluster. After an error I discarded the subscription, replication slot, and the replicated schema. After re-creating the tables and subscription the data replicated as expected. However, all subsequent changes after the initial load failed to synchronize. This included all major operation INSERT, UPDATE, & DELETE.

Comment: forgot the PK on the target table?

Comment: The answer is almost certainly in the log file.

Comment: @jjanes I was able to track down the issue after digging into logs. It wasn't obvious at first, but it turned out I'd set up the logical_replication_slot on the subscribing database rather than the publication location. Made the error creating it by hand since the slots don't auto-create when on the same cluster.